# How to know when a listitem in a listview is focused(highlighted) in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a straight way for that. All I need is when I clicked on a menu-item I can realize that which on of items in the list is focused?
For example in the blow picture how can I know which item is highlighted(when i clicked on a button for example on the Back Button)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must implement an OnItemClickListener

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       YourClass yourObject = (YourClass) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but your solution is true when i  want to click on an item but i want to click on a button for example back button and also know that which item is now highlighted? so i think that your solution is not fit.thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()

or keep a reference of the current selection.